# EF Core 6 cycle reference add new property in shadow state for one to one relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I have a .NET Core Razor Pages proyect in Visual Studio 2022 with Entity Framework Core 6 and Postgres 13 that models companies and cars.
A Car belongs to only one Company and a Company can have many Cars.
In turn, a Company may or may not have an active Car.
My model is:

```
public class Company {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        public ICollection<Car>? Cars { get; set; }
        
        public int? ActiveCarId { get; set; }
        public Car? ActiveCar { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Car {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string LicensePlate { get; set; }
        
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public Company? Company { get; set; }
    }
```

In the context I have:

```
public class CompanyCarsContext : DbContext {
        public CompanyCarsContext(DbContextOptions<CompanyCarsContext> options)
            : base(options) {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder) {
            builder.Entity<Company>().HasMany<Car>(e => e.Cars).WithOne(p => p.Company);
            builder.Entity<Company>().HasOne<Car>(e => e.ActiveCar);
        }

        public DbSet<CompanyCars.Models.Company> Companys { get; set; } = default!;

        public DbSet<CompanyCars.Models.Car> Cars { get; set; }
    }
```

When I do the migration it gives me the warning:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[10625]
> The foreign key property 'Company.ActiveCarId1' was created in shadow state because a conflicting property with the simple name
> 'ActiveCarId' exists in the entity type, but is either not mapped,
> is already used for another relationship, or is incompatible with the
> associated primary key type.        See
> https://aka.ms/efcore-relationships for information on mapping
> relationships in EF Core.

But when I remove the property ActiveCarId in class Company (removing the migrations folder as well) and do the migration again, it gives me error:

> Both relationships between 'Car.Company' and 'Company.Cars' and
> between 'Car' and 'Company.ActiveCar' could use {'CompanyId'} as the
> foreign key. To resolve this, configure the foreign key properties
> explicitly in 'OnModelCreating' on at least one of the relationships.

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Remove `ActiveCarId` and `ActiveCar` properties. Make `bool IsActive` property in `Car` class.

Comment: thanks for your answer but those changes force me to change other applications that also use the base